# jquery remove selected dropdown item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

once i select an item from dropdown, the item will be placed inside

tag as below

[image: dropdown item]

the code for html and javascript are as below

```
<select class="dropDownList" id="PersonFunction">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Vice President</option>
    <option value="2">Director</option>
    <option value="3">Secretary</option>
    <option value="4">Clerk</option>
</select>
<div class="options">
    <ul>
    </uL>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#PersonFunction").change(function() {

    var val = $("option:selected", $(this)).text();
var opt1 = '<li id="'+ $(this).val()+'">'+val+ '<a href="#" class="launch" onclick="removeItem(event)"> remove</a></li>';

    $('.options ul').append(opt1);
});
function removeItem(event){
    disabledEventPreventDefault(event);

}
</script>
```

now i need to remove the items when i click remove link which will trigger  removeItem
 function, how can i do this action.Had try many way but didn't work.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".options").on('click', 'a', function (e) {
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Another small thing: you can use `$("option:selected", this)`.  `this` does not need to be in a selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XgFCr/2/)**

```
$("#PersonFunction").change(function() {
debugger
    var val = $("option:selected", $(this)).text();
var opt1 = '<li id="'+ $(this).val()+'">'+val+ '<a href="#" class="launch" onclick="removeItem(event)"> remove</a></li>';

    $('.options ul').append(opt1);
});

$(document).on("click", ".launch", function(event){      
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});​
```

Comment: you removing the list inside dropdown list not the list that is displayed

Comment: I am removing the one is selected, and demo is working fine can you tell me how to check the problem you telling.

Comment: He doesn't want to remove the selected option in the dropdown, he wants to remove it on the list below (I'll agree that the question is unclear, though)

Comment: I just got it mean while and updated the answer thanks @Explosion Pills.